# String with varbinary to ImageView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to send a string contained a varbinary into an ImageView

```
   string ImageHexAsString = "0xFFD8FFE000104A464946000101010...";//Here is my string as VarBinary


    byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ImageHexAsString); //Here i'm converting string to byte[]
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap); //and here i'm send it to imageview
```

I get an empty white image nothing more.Is something wrong?

Comment: are you sure the data that you're decoding is the same as the original encoded data?  Have you debugged each step of the encode/decode process?

Comment: `GetBytes` will literally give you the bytes for the string. You need to find a way to convert your string representation of the bytes.

Comment: How should i check that?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just realized this is about c#, not Java. Answer is the same though. Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

This is probably a duplicate of [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

What's happening is that you shouldn't try and interpret the hex string as text (with `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`), because it isn't, it's an image.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
   ImageHexAsString = "0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100....";
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();

        string hexPart = ImageHexAsString.Substring(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < hexPart.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            string hexNumber = hexPart.Substring(i * 2, 2);
            byteList.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(hexNumber, 16));
        }

        byte[] original = byteList.ToArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(original, 0, original.Length);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

it seems to work with 256x256 resolution I dont know how to change the struck if image is bigger